# Writing a table to a matplotlib pdf file

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, latex

I am using [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) and a modified version of [this](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/pylab_examples/multipage_pdf.html) example to generate plots in pdf files. So I am plotting each plot on a single page and the results are just fine.

Now I would like to list all the data used in the plots in a rather long table. This table should be placed below the last plot (so not each plot should get its own table).

Is there a way to plot LaTeX like tables in a pdf file using matplotlib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless using a plot to write text, I think it is save to say, that it is not possible to only write a table to a matplotlib pdf output file.

Currently I am using tex to write the table and pyPdf to merge the two results. I think this is the cleanest solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, you can place almost any TeX stuff onto a plot using something like `plt.text(1,2,r'$a^2+b^2=42$')`. For aligning equations things like `eqnarray` work as well,  [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6068827/align-tex-equations-in-matplotlib/6070904#6070904).  Just don't forget to use raw strings, for otherwise python can misinterpret TeX commands which start with backslashes.

Comment: @N.N.: If ams extensions (like `align` and its relatives) work, then of course, there's no reason to use `eqnarray`. For what I've tried, at least in an older version of `matplotlib`, I didn't manage to get it to work. Hence `eqnarray`.