# Reducing the space produced in eqnarray for equal sign

Tags: latex

How can I reduce the extra phase space between the equal sign and the equations?
(It seems this question was previously answered in different softwares, i.e., Matlab, Python,..)
many thanks in advance

```
\documentclass[9pt]{osa-supplemental-document}
\setboolean{shortarticle}{false}

\title{vvvv}
\author{} %leave this blank
%% DO NOT ADD AUTHOR INFORMATION HERE; IT WILL BE ADDED DURING PRODUCTION

\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\setboolean{displaycopyright}{false} %copyright statement should not display in the  supplementary document

\begin{document}
    
    \maketitle
    \section{,,,,}\label{ss}
    I
    \begin{eqnarray} 
        S_0&=&2+2\\
                    S_0&=&ssss              
    \end{eqnarray}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't know what you mean with _phase_ space. Assuming you just mean space, maybe try _align_ (_align*_ if you don't want equation numbering) instead of _eqnarray_? Like in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39020795

Comment: Thanks @Dugon, Although I previously read your link, I think that is related to Python. It helps me here too.

Comment: The easiest way to fix all problems with `eqnarray` is to not use it.

Comment: @sara00 If you use a non-standard class, you should add to your question where we can get the class from

Comment: As Dugon suggested, I used Align package. (unfortunately, I eliminate the vote to Dugon by mistake and I can not correct it ). @samcarter-is-at-topanswers-xyz thank you for your advice (also. the class I used is related to the optica publishing group)